# How to fast forward origin/master while offline?

Tags: git

I'm using git.

I currently have no access to `origin/master` (firewalled).

Git is telling me my `master` HEAD is ahead of `origin/master` by 30 commits, but I've actually (indirectly) synchronized with it. I'd like to move `origin/master` to my `master` HEAD on my machine, without talking to `origin`.

How can this be done?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? It will be updated next time you are online, until then you cannot push to origin anyway.

Comment: I use a synchronization system that warns me if a git is out of sync with the remote. I don't like it that it's showing me warnings every time.

Answer (score 0):

hanging `.git/refs/remotes/origin/master` and writing my HEAD's commit hash there seems to have done the trick.